# How to start, kill process and write to a log file via batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I need to run a process (`.exe` file) that never ends for several seconds, then kill it and write the output to a log file. Thats what I did:

```
start OpenCloseFileTest.exe  >> D:\Roey\Jen3\SdkTest\OpenCloseFileTest\Logs\RoeyLog2.log
sleep 5                                
taskkill /f /im "OpenCloseFileTest.exe"
```

It starts and kills the process after 5 seconds but for some reason the created log file is empty.

When I am doing this:

```
OpenCloseFileTest.exe  >> D:\Roey\Jen3\SdkTest\OpenCloseFileTest\Logs\RoeyLog2.log
```

and closing the process manually the log file is OK.

Comment: The executable writes to the log file buffered via a file stream as it is done by nearly all applications to reduce the number of storage media writes. The file stream buffer is flushed to storage media on reaching maximum amount of bytes reserved for the buffer or when the file is closed. As you kill the executable, it cannot close the file resulting in writing file stream buffer to storage media and the result is an empty file. Use `taskkill` without `/f` (force kill instead of terminate) and check if the application terminates within a second.

Comment: For more details see [How does the windows kill process work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/151196/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer .i tried to use the taskkill without /f and still the same issue (empty file..)...

Comment: So the started application is a GUI application. What happens when running it and terminate it via Windows task manager from tab __Applications__ (WM_CLOSE message is sent to the application) and not from tab *Processes* (application process is killed by Windows)? Does this also result in an empty file?

Comment: yes . when running it and terminate it via Windows task manager it  also result in an empty file.

Comment: the developer had the option to close it by hitting the enter key.
so what i am doing now is running the exe file via vb script wait -pressing enter and taking the log. thats working , but for my original question there is still no solution....

Comment: Well, if the developer of the GUI application has not implemented a handling for standard signals/events from operating system to quit the application gracefully, you are lost on making usage of those standard signals. You might code a VBScript which uses SendKeys function to send RETURN to this application after some seconds.